# Entity Framework 6 - Left Join - Prevent Addition of Null Checks in Join Clause Conditions

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

Is there a way for Entity Framework to respect the "UseDatabaseNullSemantics" option in a left join?

Basically, I'd like to prevent the addition of "OR (([ExtentX].[Property] IS NULL) AND ([ExtentY].[Property] Is Null))" that gets added to the generated SQL query.  I've seen the following discussions, but none of them provide a solution that will work for my query:

[UseDatabaseNullSemantics still generating NULL checks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35900309/usedatabasenullsemantics-still-generating-null-checks/35902169)

[Why is EF generating SQL queries with unnecessary null-checks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38433594/why-is-ef-generating-sql-queries-with-unnecessary-null-checks)

[Prevent NULL checks in LINQ to Entity Joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19182319/prevent-null-checks-in-linq-to-entity-joins)

It has to be a Left Join... I cannot put the join condition in a where clause because it does not produce the same results, and I need to allow null data if there are no matches (hence the left join).

Basically, I have a query similar to:

```
 (from c in dbContext.CPUs 
 join u in dbContext.UData on c.User equals u.User into ud 
 from uds in ud.DefaultIfEmpty()
 select new ResultOjbect{});
```

And it generates this nasty SQL:

```
SELECT BLAH FROM CpuTable LEFT OUTER JOIN UserTable (ON CPUTable.User = UserTable.User) 
OR ((CpuTable.User IS NULL) AND (UserTable.User IS NULL))
```

The addition of **OR ((CpuTable.User IS NULL) AND (UserTable.User IS NULL))** causes horrible performance and makes the query take 2 minutes for 17000 records.  If you remove this from the generated SQL, it takes 23 seconds to load 17000+ records.

Why is there no option to control this?  This is incredibly unnecessary and slows my query to a crawl.  Anyone know a work-around?

Comment: *"Why is there no option to control this?"* - rhere is no need of option, it's a bug. *"Anyone know a work-around?"* - yes, the accepted answer of the duplicate, e.g. `from u in dbContext.UData.Where(u => c.User == u.User).DefaultIfEmpty()` translates to `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: You didn't understand the question, so how can you mark it as a duplicate?  It's a left join, but the query it produces leads to horrible performance because of those unnecessary nulls in the join clause.  Please re-read.  This should not be marked as a duplicate

Comment: I did read it and it is a duplicate. The accepted answer uses the alternative `left join` syntax (also shown in my previous comment adjusted for your scenario) which does not have unnecessary null checks (of course when `UseDatabaseNullSemantics` is set to `true`). No need offense, just try it.

Comment: Yeah, so how do I select those properties in my result object?

Comment: The same way you do with your current query. To be crystal clear, *replace* `join u in dbContext.UData on c.User equals u.User into ud from uds in ud.DefaultIfEmpty()` with `from uds in dbContext.UData.Where(u => c.User == u.User).DefaultIfEmpty()`. Ok?
`

Comment: You're right.  That appears to work.  Thanks for your help!  So what I was doing before was incorrect and did produce the correct SQL for the way I had written it in query syntax, or is it a bug?

Comment: You are welcome. And you are doing nothing wrong, it's a EF bug :( and this is the workaround.